# pass a sql parameter into a dynamically created user control C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a gridview user control with a sqldatasource calling a stored procedure.  The user control is dynamically created on the aspx page and I have everything working without passing any parameters in.  I cannot figure out how to pass the parameters in the user control.  Here is a minimized version of the code.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Survey.ascx.cs" Inherits="AppSurvey" %>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswerCount" runat="server" Columns="5" MaxLength="5" />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" 
                        Display="None" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtAnswerCount" ErrorMessage = "Count values must be entered as integer values." />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:1316 %>" SelectCommand="dbo.usp_Survey" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Category" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;

namespace EUCNET01316
{
    public partial class Survey : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["Category"].DefaultValue = ?????;
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
            GridView1.DataBind();  
        }
    }
}


**** ASPX Page

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl ctl = Page.LoadControl("Survey.ascx") as UserControl;
    Panel PB = new Panel();
    PB.Controls.Add(ctl);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but this is one... In your user control's codebehind you can create a public property to accept your parameter or the value that you will assign to your sql parameter:

```
namespace EUCNET01316
{
    public partial class Survey : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["Category"].DefaultValue = MyParameterValue;
             GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
             GridView1.DataBind();  
         }

         public string MyParameterValue {get;set;}
     }
 }
```

Then in your ASPX page markup, add a directive to reference to the user control:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/Usercontrols/Survey.ascx" %>
```

Then in the codebehind, cast your user control as its type instead of just "UserControl"

```
Survey ctl = Page.LoadControl("Survey.ascx") as Survey;
// set the property
ctl.MyParameterValue = "foo";
```

Now in your codebehind you can set the property you created on your user control.  Just make sure you set the property BEFORE attempting to load the control into the page's control collection (at which point the lifecycle will try to "catch up," and your control's page_load will fire prior to the property being set).

Comment: Sorry to ask such a dumb question but this is the first user control I have attempted to use,  I don't know what you mean by "set the property you created on your user control."

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! YOU ARE AWESOME!!!!! I have spent so many hours trying to make this work.

Comment: @Mike Accept the answer if it helped you.